# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined when it is opened on localhost

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new on AngularJS and I got that error.

```
,app.controller("prjNewData", ["$scope", function($scope,$http) {

$http.get('http://server/mndrest/index.php/api/example/taskpriority').

    then(function(response){

        $scope.taskpriority = response.data;
    })  
    }]);
```

Comment: `["$scope",` => `["$scope", "$http",`

Comment: You're only injecting `"$scope"` into your controller, try: `["$scope", "$http",  function($scope,$http)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your injection

```
["$scope", function($scope,$http) {
```

to

```
["$scope", "$http", function($scope,$http) {
```